# Why is python requests throwing this BadStatusLine exception

Tags: python, exception, python-requests

In python if I import requests and do:

```
t = requests.get("http://www.azlyrics.com/u/urban.html")
```

I get this exception:

```
raise BadStatusLine(line)
http.client.BadStatusLine: ''
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There can be [different](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1767934/771848) [reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28557466/771848) [for this kind of error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33174804/771848), but in this particular case this looks like a simple *web-scraping detection* - it can be solved by providing a *User-Agent header* pretending to be a real browser:

```
In [2]: requests.get("http://www.azlyrics.com/u/urban.html")
...
ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', BadStatusLine("''",))

In [3]: requests.get("http://www.azlyrics.com/u/urban.html", headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.75 Safari/537.36'})
Out[3]: <Response [200]>
```

Comment: I forget that I have adjusted nginx to refuse "bad user agents". Now I was bad. Thanks a lot. ( orginal code I wrote in php, I couldnt find solution then moved whole project to python for that stupid self feature )