# h2o server disconnects from local PC

Tags: python, h2o

I'm using H2O 3.24 with python 3.6 and the connection to the H2O server, which is on my local machine, will either freeze and/or crash with the error:

H2OConnectionError: Unexpected HTTP error: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response',))

This has happened with previous versions of H2O, and isn't strictly reproducible, it will happen randomly. Sometimes the process will finish and sometimes it will crash. I see a little discussion of this online but there never seems to be a resolution.

Comment: I guess that this type of issue is related to what is discuss for https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/3458. However is not clear how you configure your H2O server, and what look your python client. In question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33174804/python-requests-getting-connection-aborted-badstatusline-error/33226080, that can be consider related to it, you see inclusive examples of python client.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I'm not sure it's related to the first, as there is no mention of an H2Oserver. This type of error only occurs when running H2O. As for the second, I've done some scraping like this example but never had an error like this, it really seemed to be connect to H2O. I'm not sure how to answer how my python client is configured. python 3.6 is installed locally, as is H2O through pip, nothing fancy.

Comment: What is the output of `java -version`? I've seen this happen when a 32bit version of java uses up all of its memory.

Comment: Thanks Joe. 
` java version "1.8.0_111" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_111-b14) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.111-b14, mixed mode) `

Comment: If you post the full output from the h2o server we might be able to determine where the error logs from the JVM are stored (or you could look yourself) and continue troubleshooting. However, since there have been a number of bug fixes to the JVM after  `java version "1.8.0_111"`, I'm inclined to think you should update to the most recent Java 8. This may resolve the issue.

Comment: I upgraded to 1.8.0_211 but unfortunately that didn't help. 
#sdf

Comment: The only error from the h2o server that might be related is below:
2019-07-02 07:55:32.889:WARN:oejs.ServletHandler:Error for /3/Logs/nodes/127.0.0.1:54321/files/stdout
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

I haven't had much luck finding error logs. would they come in the form system.out, systemerr.log, system.err, java.log, javaerr.log ... ?

Comment: It looks like you're running out of heap memory. Are you launching h2o3 from python or from the command line? You may want to use `min_mem_size` if launching from python http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/starting-h2o.html#from-python. If launching from the command line try something like, `java -Xmx10g -jar h2o.jar` which would allocate 10g of memory for H2O.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't solve it. I'm launching from python, set min_mem_size to 6, and I'm seeing it has plenty of memory overhead when it crashes. Another error that occurs before the memory error is:

Exception in thread "Multi-UDP-R" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.SocketException: Invalid argument
 at water.MultiReceiverThread.run(MultiReceiverThread.java:76)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Invalid argument

Comment: Also:
#ti-UDP-R ERRR: Turning off multicast, which will disable further cloud building